# Size of <div> should stay always the same

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

so i have this code to display a card (panel) that consists of a picture with a link below. Right now the hight of the div changes with every image because the images are different sizes.
I would like that the divs are always the same height no matter the image size.

Propably it is just a css change. Any ideas?

```
<div class ="row" style="margin-top: 40px;">
  <h3 style="text-align: center; color:#000;">Top Walls near you</h3><br/>
  <% @walls.each do |wall| %>
  <div class ="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class ="panel-heading preview">
      <%= link_to wall do %>
      <%= image_tag wall.cover_photo(:medium) %>
      <% end %>

    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="box-shadow: 2px 27px 25px -19px rgba(176,176,176,1);">
      <%= link_to wall.address, wall %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your HTML markup (and additional CSS if any) here? That will help in answering the question.

Comment: define the div height and width. Probably width:100%

Comment: No only your images are different size but different scale ratio. Try to crop the images to have the same proportion as the other ones (4:3, 16:9) and they will look more even.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Just set a default value to the div element with "width" property :

```
<div width = "1000px"></div>
```

or

css:

```
 div {width:1000px;}
```

You can add the image tag or the div tag you are using inside the div with the default size and control the appearance width the overflow property. Example:

css:
      overflow: hidden;

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is resize the images to fit in the div's height. So first we iterate over the images (I don't know where are yours, `preview` class?) then we set the height like his parent, here an example:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".images img").forEach(function(i){
i.height = i.parentElement.clientHeight;
})
```

```css
.images{
  height: 100px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/Dickweiler_Wegekreuz.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="images">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Echternach_mairie.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="images">

</div>
```

In this case i'm using `clientHeight` (includes just padding) but could be `offsetHeight` (includes padding, scrollBar and borders)